# my window.onscroll event not working

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, addeventlistener, onscroll

I am trying to make the opacity of an image transition to 0 after the user scroll a certain amount. Not sure why but the javascript function is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```js
var bengalsedit = document.getElementsByClassName("bengals_edited");
console.log(bengalsedit);

window.onscroll = function() {
  addOpacity()
};

function addOpacity() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200) {
    bengalsedit.style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.bengals_edited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 850px 0 0 0;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bengals_edited img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bengals_edited">

  <img id="bengals_edit" src="media/Photographs/Edited_Photos/2015Sep03%20-%20Bengals%20vs%20Colts%20-%20103.jpg">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

bengalsedit is a collection, not an element.

> bengalsedit[0].style.opacity=0;

Comment: Works only if you're sure if there is just 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

You're using getElementByClassName. This is returning an HTMLCollection in stead of a single element. This can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. use getElementById and set an id on the element, or
2. get the first element of the collection by using: `bengalsedit[0]`

If you have more then 1 element to set the opcity to you need to loop through the HTMLCollecion.

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)